# ServiceStack IP restiction with filters

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

In my ServiceStack app I'm trying to restict all the users except the ones whos IP is present in a white list, the only way I found to do that was to use PreRequestFilters in my Configure method:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) =>
{
    if (!ipWhiteList.Contains(req.RemoteIp))
    {
        res.ContentType = req.ResponseContentType;
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.Dto = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse("401", "Unauthorized", null);
        res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

Is this achievable by custom Authentication filters (if that is possible at all)? Maybe there are some out of the box features that allow to do that or simply best practices to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a [Request Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes#filter-attributes-example) for this, e.g:

```
public class ValidateIpAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute 
{
    public IpValidator IpValidator { get; set; }

    public void RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        if (IpValidator.Allow(req.RemoteIp))
            return;

        res.ContentType = req.ResponseContentType;
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.Dto = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse("401", "Unauthorized", null);
        res.EndRequest();
    }
}
```

Which you can then use on your Services, e.g:

```
[ValidateIp]
public class ProtectedServices : Service
{
}
```

Comment: but this filter will not trigget  during authorization attempt, right?

Comment: @HardLuck By default it has a Priority of `0` which gets executed after `[Authenticate]` [which has lower priority](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7ada40fd19881229afdb8e9d8f0d9ab344e57605/src/ServiceStack/RequestFilterAttribute.cs#L8) and any [Global Request Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) but before the Service is executed.

Comment: but even if i redefine Priority in my filter like public static new int Priority => -2; it still doesn't run before Authentication

Comment: @HardLuck I linked to the [Priority of built-in Request Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7ada40fd19881229afdb8e9d8f0d9ab344e57605/src/ServiceStack/RequestFilterAttribute.cs#L8) previously, the [Authenticate] attribute has a priority of -100. A priority < 0 is just executed before Global Request Filters.

Comment: Strange, but even setting Priority to -110 and -300 didn't execute it first, so i beleive i just need PreRequestFilter

Comment: @HardLuck we've got tests showing otherwise, are you adding the attribute on the Service class? Because [Action/method-level attributes are executed in their own scope](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes#action-filter-attributes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103749/discussion-between-hardluck-and-mythz).

Comment: The request filter has nothing to do with Auth and will not fire unless Service action is called, so everything works as expected, thank you